# How should I use SAML login with a REST API + SPA app?

Tags: rest, saml

I want to use SAML login for a single web application with a REST API. How should I do this? Usually, say with OAuth, lets use Google/Firebase as an example:

- SPA calls Google to login. Google returns a Google ID token
- SPA can call Server with Google ID token which server can verify with Google and return an access token for use with the application

Firstly is this correct or did I get something wrong so far?

---

But with SAML, from what I can see, its user is redirected to SAML IDP, SAML IDP then redirects user to a server assertion URL. Because there is this redirect, how do I use it in the context of REST? I am unfamiliar with SAML, but I dont see a token. The server just gets an "assertion" with the user information?

Comment: Have you had the answer for your question?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the sequence of events which happen when the application is using SAML for the authentication:

1. server should send a response to the client with the URL to SAML IDP.
2. client application redirects the browser to SAML IDP (1).
3. After successful authentication, SAML server sends response with the redirect back to the client. The browser automatically posts the HTML form SAML server to your server.
4. After validating SAML assert and successful authorization (you can use user's information or other attributes to authorize the user to use your application), your server should generate a token that now can be used by the client application.

This is a basic scenario.

See spirng-saml project here, you can try and play with the sample web application. 
https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml

Comment: I don't think your comment answers the op's question. In step 4, after generating a token, how the server can send it back to the client application since the browser is still in SAML IDP page?

Comment: @LittleZero use 302 redirect

Answer (score 1):

SAML assertion is an equivalent of id_token in OpenID Connect 1.0 that Google uses. There is no access_token in SAML. SAML is an authentication protocol.

OAuth 2.0 that uses access_tokens is an authorization protocol. That is why it provides an access_token to authorize access to your REST API.

OpenID Connect is an extension of OAuth 2.0 that supports user authentication in addition to API authorization and introduces id_tokens that contain user information.

One of the options to use SAML in your Single Page Application with REST API is to host them at the same domain. In this case you can:

1. Get an assertion from SAML Identity Provider.
2. Verify it (format, signature, lifetime, etc) on the server side.
3. Return a session cookie in the response to set it in the browser.
4. Each request to the REST API will come with a session cookie authorizing access to it.